# Problem in burning a DVD and getting the iso file

Tags: 13.04

I just downloaded the Ubuntu 13.04 OS(32-bit) desktop version. It is a Zip file, i extracted the contents of it and burned it into DVD. But i cannot see the iso file, and how to make it bootable. Please help with this because i really want to try it out.
And i am using Windows 7 right now.

Answer (score 2):

The file you downloaded is an ISO, but since it doesn't have anything associated with it, it will look as a ZIP file.  What you can do is download [ImageBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/index.php?act=download).  ImgBurn is a free burning software fir windows.

Now I believe that this is what you saw

[image]

In my case I have PowerISO installed, so what I did was, right click the file, and choose open with, and Clicked on choose default program, and choose power ISO

[image]

And once done this is the outcome

[image]

So once you download and install ImageBurn, click on write image file to disk, and  choose the file that you have downloaded.

[image]

Comment: The questioner also wants to know how to make that file bootable ( and maybe how to boot from an DVD).

Comment: @Frank The Ubuntu ISO file is a bootable image, and once burned to a DVD, you can boot from that DVD.  You may have to change the boot option in your system's BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

instead of wasting another disk, try using a USB drive. Windows I know has a nice tool for creating bootable disks (usb and dvd) you just need to make sure when you're downloading ubuntu that you have the correct download
you can actually just google 'ubuntu 13.04 iso' and it should be the first or second result.
the windows disk writer tool i am referring to is listed in step 2 on this nice how to guide.
http://arstechnica.com/business/2009/12/the-usb-flash-drive/
just replace windows with ubuntu :D

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you download directly from the [Ububtu](http://www.ubuntu.com) site and not some zipped file from somewhere else. You will get a .iso file that you must burn on a CD as **image**. If you burn it as a file it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

actually you can create .iso file of your unziped cotent through poweriso  and  then you can burn CD or DVD of that iso file by poweriso or make boot able USB stick by poweriso ......means power iso can used for all the thing no need of other soft wear ...please ignore my english